# Select Rows from Different Table where String from 1st table column is present in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr, fuzzy

I am trying to match tables if a string is fully present in the other tables' column. However, I have managed to join it partially and then I am applying Levenstein distance to get close matches. This approach has limited use and accuracy. Approach:

```
checkg <- check %>% 
  fuzzy_inner_join(LOCATIONS, by = c("STRING" = "STRING"), match_fun = str_detect) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(DIST = adist(x=STRING, y=LOCATION, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

is there any way to map it in the following way?  The STATUS column in the output table is just given to make it clear that partial string matching is not the objective.  It is not required in the output. Thanks

`TABLE 1`

```
**STRING** 
BATANGAS
QINGDAO
```

`TABLE2`

```
**STRING**
BATNAGAS LUZON
QINGDAO PT
```

`OUTPUT TABLE checkg`

```
TABLE1.STRING   TABLE2.STRING    STATUS
BATANGAS        BATNAGAS LUZON   Accept
QINGDAO         QINGDAO PT       Accept
BATANGAS        TANGA            Reject
```

Comment: I presume check is table1 and loactions is table 2.  Is it?

Comment: Yes. check is Table 1 where odd strings exist, LOCATIONS IS table where the correct ones are saved.

Comment: so where is `TANGA` saved as value in your sample?

Comment: TANGA is saved in LOCATIONS

Comment: Ok. That means tanga is nearest fuzzy match, but why is status for that rejected? Do you have some threshold limit for match/distance?

Comment: Got it! Let me check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the syntax to avoid partial matching from LOCATIONS table.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

check <- data.frame(STRING = c("BATANGAS", "QINGDAO"))
LOCATIONS <- data.frame(STRING = c("BATANGAS LUZON", "QINGDAO PT", "TANGA"))

LOCATIONS %>% 
  fuzzy_right_join(check, by = c("STRING" = "STRING"), match_fun = str_detect)

        STRING.x STRING.y
1 BATANGAS LUZON BATANGAS
2     QINGDAO PT  QINGDAO
```

To check further for full words only, you can do this..

```
check <- structure(list(To_check = c("BATANGAS", "QINGDAO", "ABC", "DEF"
), id = 1:4), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

check
> check
  To_check id
1 BATANGAS  1
2  QINGDAO  2
3      ABC  3
4      DEF  4

> LOCATIONS
          STRING
1 BATANGAS LUZON
2     QINGDAO PT
3          TANGA
4           ABCD

LOCATIONS %>% 
  fuzzy_right_join(check %>% mutate(dummy = paste0('\\b', To_check, '\\b')), 
                   by = c("STRING" = "dummy"), match_fun = str_detect) %>%
  select(-dummy)

          STRING To_check id
1 BATANGAS LUZON BATANGAS  1
2     QINGDAO PT  QINGDAO  2
3           <NA>      ABC  3
4           <NA>      DEF  4
```

*needless to say you can use `fuzzy_inner_join` for having matched results only*

Comment: Thanks. Works well with some adjustments like str_length() > x. Smaller strings needed to be filtered out as they me be present frequently.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nature of your tables but in general this is the solution I came up with:

```
Table1 <- data.table(STRING = c("BATANGAS", "QINGDAO"))
Table2 <- data.table(STRING = c("BATANGAS LUZON", "QINGDAO PT", "TANGA"))

Table3 <- as.data.table(stringdist_join(Table1, Table2, by = "STRING", max_dist = 6, method = "lv", 
                                        mode = "full", distance_col = "STATUS"))
```

I am not familiar enough with dplyr to replicate it there so I am using data.table in my example.

This code will produce the following result:

```
STRING.x    STRING.y          STATUS
BATANGAS    BATANGAS LUZON    6
BATANGAS    TANGA             3
QINGDAO     QINGDAO PT        3
QINGDAO     TANGA             4
```

Now it gets a bit tricky. I can imagine that you don't want TANGA to match with two different values in STRING.x. However in this example you do want BATANGAS to match with 2 different values in STRING.y. If you want to **always** remove duplicates from STRING.y you can do so by using this:

```
Table3 <- Table3[ , .SD[which.min(STATUS)], by = STRING.y]
```

which will produce:

```
STRING.y          STRING.x    STATUS
BATANGAS LUZON    BATANGAS    6
TANGA             BATANGAS    3
QINGDAO PT        QINGDAO     3
```